# JSON to java object different attributes

Tags: java, json

I am using jackson to convert json to java object, but the problem I am facing is that say the json format is:

```
{
  employeeId: 123
  name: akash
  ........some other attributes
}
```

and the java object i am converting it to, has attributes:

```
id:
name:
.....some other attributes
```

Now I want to convert that json into the object, you can see that all the attributes have same name, except for employeeid/id.
Considering that I can't change the json nor the java object. How can I go about it to do the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on the getter method of `id` in your model class.

```
@JsonProperty("employeeId")
```

Comment: thanks, btw after adding this, will both id and employeeId work?

Comment: It will map employeeId from Json to your id in model class. If you have another member variable id in your model class, you dont need to do the above mentioned mapping at all

Comment: If there are two variables in your model class, say id and employeeId, Json property will automatically be mapped to employeeId in model class and id will be null

Comment: My question was say in some case I want id to be mapped, and in some employee id to be mapped. How to do that? The case required has only one of them present. I am asking if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can used [@JsonProperty("nameOfProperty")](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) which is used for

> Property to serialize (when applied to a "getter" method)
>     Property to deserialize (when applied to a "setter" method) Field-backed
>   property to serialize and deserialize (when applied to a non-static
>   member

field)

So your call look like

```
class abc
{
   @jsonProperty("employeeId")
   int id;  

   //your other class variable and getter-setter methods
}
```